# What is the equivalent for swift REPL of Python's python -i thisfiletoload.py?

Tags: swift, read-eval-print-loop, interactive-mode

What is the equivalent for swift REPL of Python's python -i thisfiletoload.py ? Thanks.  i.e.

```
python -i thisfiletoload.py
```

in the command prompt. What's the swift REPL equivalent?

Comment: Did my answer help you?  Please mark it as accepted if it has.

Comment: No. When I type at the command prompt swift [file.swift] , after the swift file runs, it returns back to the command prompt as opposed to staying in REPL along with all variables declared.

Answer (score 0):

Swift used to have a `-i` "input" flag, but that flag is deprecated and no longer necessary.

Running `swift [file.swift]` from the command line will result in the behavior you desire.

`test.swift`:

```
println("hello")
let x = 1
println("x = \(x)")
```

Console Output:

```
➜  Test  swift test.swift
hello
x = 1
```

With `-i`:

```
➜  Test  swift -i test.swift
<unknown>:0: error: the flag '-i' is no longer required and has been removed; use 'swift input-filename'
```

Version:

```
➜  Test  swift --version
Apple Swift version 1.2 (swiftlang-602.0.53.1 clang-602.0.53)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I've only been able to accomplish this by first converting the file into a module.

```
$ swiftc filename.swift -emit-library -sdk $( xcrun --sdk macosx --show-sdk-path) -emit-module -module-link-name MyCode -module-name MyCode -lSystem
```

That will compile your file, and create a .dylib and .swiftmodule in the current directory ( to which you must of course have read-write access).  Then, from that same directory, just:

`$ swift -L. -I.`

***Welcome to Apple Swift version 5.2.2 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.6 clang-1103.0.32.51).
Type :help for assistance.***

**1>** `import MyCode`

**2>** `/// Begin using your module's code...`

---

As a .bashrc function you could:

```
repl_mod () {
    SDK=$( xcrun --sdk macosx --show-sdk-path)
    MODNAME=${1%.swift}
    $( xcrun -f swiftc) $1 -emit-library -sdk $SDK -emit-module -module-link-name $MODNAME -module-name $MODNAME -lSystem
}
```

Which would produce a module in the current directory, named after your filename:

`repl_mod mycode.swift`

`swift -L. -I.`
...

**>1** `import mycode`

If you modify the command to output its results somewhere other than the current directory, be sure to convey that change to the REPL via the `-L` and `-I` args.